# Why API Gateway websocket publish a https connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway websocket endpoint and I see there are two endpoints created after deploy. One is `https` the other is `wss`. I can use websocket client to connect to my service via the websocket endpoint. I wonder why it creates a `https` endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is to [use @connections commands in your backend service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html).

With the https endpoint:

> Your **backend service** can use the following WebSocket connection **HTTP requests** to send a callback message to a connected client, get connection information, or disconnect the client.